# How to implement @dataclass to define arithmetic operations in Python?

Tags: python, oop, python-dataclasses, structural-pattern-matching

I'm learning Python on my own and I found a task that requires using a decorator @dataclass to create a class with basic arithmetic operations.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from numbers import Number

@dataclass
class MyClass:
    x: float
    y: float
    def __add__(self, other):
         match other:
            case Number():
                return MyClass(float(other) + self.x, self.y)    
            case MyClass(ot_x, ot_y):
                return MyClass(self.x + ot_x, self.y + ot_y)
              
    __radd__ = __add__
```

I have implemented the addition operation. But I also need to do the operations of subtraction `__sub__`, multiplication `__mul__`, division `__truediv__`, negation `__neg__`, also `__mod__` and `__pow__`. But I couldn't realize these operations. The main thing for me is to use the construction match/case. Maybe there are simpler ways to create it.
I will be glad of your help.

Comment: `number.Number` doesn't work like you might hope, in fact, that whole numeric tower idea has been essentially abandoned. use the numeric types specifically

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Not being fully up to date on `match`, I trust you that `Number` won't work, but I'm unclear on why you think the numeric tower has been abandoned. In practice, they should be using `numbers.Real` (because it's the first level that actually guarantees `float(other)` would work), but I don't know of any reason not to use the ABCs from `numbers` are abandoned.

Comment: The way your `MyClass` works looks a lot like a complex number. Perhaps you can save yourself from having to implement most of the operations by simply inheriting from `complex` and overriding a few methods such as `__init__` and `__str__` to make it appear how you want it to.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to make a complete numeric type, I strongly suggest checking out the implementation of the `fractions.Fraction` type in [the `fractions` source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/fractions.py). The class was intentionally designed as a model for how you'd overload all the pairs of operators needed to implement a numeric type at the Python layer (it's explicitly pointed out in [the `numbers` module's guide to type implementers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#notes-for-type-implementors)).

The critical parts for minimizing boilerplate begin with the definition of the `_operator_fallbacks` utility function within the class (which is used to take a single implementation of the operation and the paired `operator` module function representing it, and generate the associated `__op__` and `__rop__` operators, being type strict for the former and relaxed for the latter, matching the intended behavior of each operator based on whether it's the first chance or last chance to implement the method).

It's far too much code to include here, but to show how you'd implement addition using it, I'll adapt your code to call it (you'd likely use a slightly different implementation of `_operator_fallbacks`, but the idea is the same):

```
import operator

# Optional, but if you want to act like built-in numeric types, you
# should be immutable, and using slots (if you can rely on Python 3.10+)
# dramatically reduce per-instance memory overhead
# Pre-3.10, since x and y don't have defaults, you could define __slots__ manually
@dataclass(frozen=True, slots=True)
class MyClass:
    x: float
    y: float

    # _operator_fallbacks defined here
    # When it received a non-MyClass, it would construct a MyClass from it, e.g.
    # to match your original code it would construct it as MyClass(float(val), 0)
    # and then invoke the monomorphic_operator, e.g. the _add passed to it below
    # or, if the type did not make sense to convert to MyClass, but it made sense
    # to convert the MyClass instance to the other type, it would do so, then use the
    # provided fallback operator to perform the computation
    # For completely incompatible types, it just returns NotImplemented

    def _add(a, b):
        """a + b"""
        return MyClass(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y)  # _operator_fallback has already coerced the types appropriately

    __add__, __radd__ = _operator_fallbacks(_add, operator.add)
```

By putting the ugliness of type-checking and coercion in common code found in `_operator_fallbacks`, and putting only the real work of addition in `_add`, it avoids a *lot* of every-operator-overload boilerplate (as you can see here; `_operator_fallbacks` will be a page of code to make the forward and reverse functions and return them, but each new operator is only a few lines, defining the monomorphic operator and calling `_operator_fallbacks` to generate the `__op__`/`__rop__` pair.